# How to convert ms sql db records to json records in web api

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api

am am trying to display a grid in w2ui with web api call, am new to web api so when am doing this am getiing

```
"ContentEncoding": null,
  "ContentType": null,
  "Data": [
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "Name": "test guy",
      "Address": "20 Glover Avenue",
      "Email": "test@napower.com",
      "Postal": "06850"
    },
```

**how can i change "ContentType": json ? and send to w2ui grid**

or

**any help how can i return json result in web api call ??**

webapi controller

```
public JsonResult GetAll()
        {
            return _repository.GetAll();
        }
```

Repository

```
 JsonResult GetAll();
 public JsonResult GetAll()
        {
            JsonResult JsonData = new JsonResult();
            JsonData.Data = db.UserAccounts.ToList();
            return JsonData;

        }
```

w2ui view

```
$(function() {
        $('#grid')
            .w2grid({
                name: 'grid',
                url: 'api/UserAcc',
                method: 'GET',
                columns: [
                    { field: 'Name', name:'', caption: 'Name', size: '100%' },
                    { field: 'email', caption: 'Email', size: '100%' },
                    { field: 'Address', caption: 'Address', size: '120px', render: 'money' },
                    { field: 'Postal', caption: 'Postal', size: '120px', render: 'date' }
                ]

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"ContentEncoding": null,
"ContentType": null,
"Data": [
{
  "Id": 1,
  "Name": "test guy",
  "Address": "20 Glover Avenue",
  "Email": "test@napower.com",
  "Postal": "06850"
}
```

This is whole HttpResponse. This response is already formated as json. The data to use is in array object called "Data" and data in it is also in json format.

```
"ContentType":"application/json"
```

Also you should change Content type to application/json, so browser understands that server is sending json object.

For more information you can look into this example for Web Api : [Getting started with ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api)

I hope I answered your question.

**UPDATE**

I looked into W2UI documentation and found this example

```
$(function () {
    $('#grid').w2grid({
       name: 'grid',
       header: 'List of Names',
       columns: [
                { field: 'Name', name:'', caption: 'Name', size: '100%' },
                { field: 'email', caption: 'Email', size: '100%' },
                { field: 'Address', caption: 'Address', size: '120px', render: 'money' },
                { field: 'Postal', caption: 'Postal', size: '120px', render: 'date' }
       ],
       records: [
           { Id: 1, Name: "test guy", Address: "20 Glover venue",Email:"test@napower.com",Postal:"06850"}          
       ]
   });
});
```

So the records from Web api should be placed into records property

Comment: @MNMOHAMED  { field: 'email', caption: 'Email', size: '100%' } at field property shouldn't there be Email with Captial letter?

Comment: @MNMOHAMED As I understoond, w2ui is not displaying records? Have you looked into this page? http://w2ui.com/web/get-started There is working example, and as I saw you are missing one property Records